# How to generate new page in the same tab with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

On the HTML page I have some anchor elements and click eventListner for every anchor like this:

```
<a href="letters/1" class="letter">
    <span class="letter-title">Title</span>
    <span class="letter-text">Text</span>
</a>
```

The thing is there's no such page as "/letters/1" or even "/letters" because I want to make it dynamically, generate depending on which 'a' tag gets clicked either letters/1 or letters/2 and etc. I know how I would generate HTML code of the newly created page. For that purpose I have letter.html which inner HTML holds the template and is going to be modified to display a letter. What I don't know is:

1. Is it possible to makeup the url to look like "/letters/1" instead of "/letter.html"?
2. I've tried to make click event on anchor do a redirect to the letter.html but only managed to open this page in another tab. When I try to override the redirection in click event it still tries to open "letters/1" even though function returns false as suggested in other questions on this site.

   ```
   let letterItems = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');

    letterItems.forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", () => {
        window.location = './letters.html'
        return false
    }))
   ```

The above doesn't work, and I also tried to use 'window.location.replace' or assign. For some reason only the 'window.open()' worked.

My other guess is since we already have every letter on the page and it's title and text we can on anchor click event replace the whole HTML with letter content but doesn't seem elegant and still I don't know how to prevent going to "letters/1" and it doesn't answer the question 1)

Comment: @HereticMonkey It looks helpful, I will look into it. You actually helped me to say it better: what I'm trying to do really does look like SPA. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate and get the href attribute

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  const page = document.getElementById('page');
  container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('a.letter');
    if (!tgt) return; // not a letter
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
    const letter = tgt.getAttribute('href');
    console.log(letter);
    page.innerHTML = `${letter}: ${tgt.innerHTML}`;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="letters/1" class="letter">
    <span class="letter-title">Title 1</span>
    <span class="letter-text">Text 1</span>
  </a>
  <br/>
  <a href="letters/2" class="letter">
    <span class="letter-title">Title 2</span>
    <span class="letter-text">Text 2</span>
  </a>
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, now I'm able to disable default behaviour of anchor.  I will try to combine this with what other contributor suggested.